# path data type does't take the complete url with '?' in it

Tags: python, bottle

Example: /open/123/http://x.com/wordpress/?p=592

```
@route('/open/<item_id:int>/<url:path>')
def open(item_id , url):
    print url
```

The output of this print is

'http://x.com/wordpress/'

What i want is the full url

'http://x.com/wordpress/?p=592'

i want the full url because i am going to record the user click and then direct him to it.

Comment: what exactly are looking to acheive..you need to make your question a bit clearer

Comment: hope it is more clear now, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routes only match the URL *path*, not the *query* (RFC 3986 section 3.4). Try this instead:

```
@route('/open/<item_id:int>/<url:path>')
def open(item_id , url):
    if request.query_string:
        url += '?' + request.query_string
    print url
```

Answer (score 1):

you would need something like

```
@route('/open/<item_id:int>/<url:path>/<stuff_after_slash:whatevertype>')
def open(item_id , url, stuff_after_slash):
    print url + stuff_after_slash
```

Comment: I believe that the route function only receives the path without the stuff beyond the '?' because it is considered as a part with the query :(

Comment: you can extract the _query_ and append to the path manually to get the full required path